# Scala hadoop dataframe different row formats

Tags: scala, hadoop, dataframe

I have a dataframe from hadoop that looks more or less like this

```
{x:1, y: {a:2,b:3}}
{a:4,b:5}
```

The row format is incoherent- sometimes the whole structure is OK, and sometimes one level is missing (eg. column **x** and **y**, and columns **y.a** and **y.b** are called **a** and **b**.

When i am performing an operation
`df.withColumn("newColumn", "y.a")` 
i get an error because is some rows the column **y.a** does not exist. What can i do in this case??

Comment: can you share your tried codes? mostly the code that you use to convert the input to dataframe.

Comment: df.withColumn("newColumn", "y.a")- it fails here. df is a DataFrame

Comment: can you share the schema of your df dataframe?